# React JS - How to pass variables (parameters) when using a local JSON file?

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

My page is consuming data from an API/JSON and passes **two parameters** via the API URL:

The code:

```
fetchSegments(building, reselect) {
    const bearerToken = this.getToken();

    const simulations = filter(simulationJson, { clientName: building.clientName}/ ${building.siteName} )

    //fetch(`theapiurl.net/api/simulations/${building.clientName}/${building.siteName}`, {
    // method: 'GET',
    // headers: {
    //            'Content-type': 'application/json',
    //            'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearerToken}`
    //           },
    //      })
    //     .then(response => {
    //       if(!response.ok && response.status === 404) {
    //         this.setState({ segments: [], selected: undefined })
    //        return Promise.reject(response);
    //       }
    //       return response.json();
    //     })
    //     .then(simulation => {
    //         let selectIndex = 0;
    //         if(reselect) {
    //           selectIndex = this.state.selected;
    //        }
    this.setState({ segments: simulation.segments, selected: selectIndex })
    this.props.onSelect(simulation.segments[selectIndex], reselect)
    //   })
  }
```

I currently have to consume the JSON file locally and so I commented out the bits of code in the above snippet, but I get a syntax error when trying to append the second parameter:

```
const simulations = filter(simulationJson, { clientName: building.clientName}/ **${building.siteName**} )
```

I was able to fix the syntax issue in another file that uses only one parameter, but having issues when it comes to passing two. ...could I get some help with this please

Comment: What do you actually want to pass as the second argument?

Comment: I'm passing the client name as the first argument and for the second, the siteName: Example when using the online (see my Fetch statement) API URL:theapiurl.net/api/simulations/${building.clientName}/${building.siteName} ...Now that am working with a local JSON file, am trying to figure out how do do it locally.

Comment: The first argument to `filter` function seems to be `simulationJson`, and second and third have to be `building.clientName` and `building.siteName`? We don't have context on what filter function is doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure this objects have values, you can try an alternate method,

```
fetch('theapiurl.net/api/simulations/'+building.clientName+'/'+building.siteName)
```